# Linux Char Driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Can anyone tell me how a Char Driver is bind to the corresponding physical device?

Also, I would like to know where inside a char driver we are specifying the physical device related information, which can be used by kernel to do the binding.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

A global array — bdev_map for block and cdev_map for character devices — is used to implement a hash table, which employs the device major number as hash key.

while registering for char driver following calls get in invoked to get major and minor numbers.

int register_chrdev_region(dev_t from, unsigned count, const char *name)
int alloc_chrdev_region(dev_t *dev, unsigned baseminor, unsigned count,
const char *name);

After a device number range has been obtained, the device needs to be activated by adding it to the character device database.

void cdev_init(struct cdev *cdev, const struct file_operations *fops);
int cdev_add(struct cdev *p, dev_t dev, unsigned count);

Here on cdev structure initialize with file operation and respected character device.

Whenever a device file is opened, the various filesystem implementations invoke the init_special_inode function to create the inode for a block or character device file.

```
void init_special_inode(struct inode *inode, umode_t mode, dev_t rdev)
{
inode->i_mode = mode;
if (S_ISCHR(mode)) {
inode->i_fop = &def_chr_fops;
inode->i_rdev = rdev;
} else if (S_ISBLK(mode)) {
inode->i_fop = &def_blk_fops;
inode->i_rdev = rdev;
}
else
printk(KERN_DEBUG "init_special_inode: bogus i_mode (%o)\n",
mode);
}
```

now the default_chr_fpos [chrdev_open](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/char_dev.c)() method will get invoked. which will look up for the inode->rdev device in cdev_map array and will get a instance of cdev structure. with the reference to cdev it will bind the file->f_op to cdev  file operation and invoke the open method for character driver.

Comment: Thanks !! But, where are we specifying the HW specific details in the char driver ??

Comment: My main doubt is how char driver will pass the vendor/HW specific details to the kernel, which will help the kernel to bind it to corresponding device.

Comment: what is the exact scenario and problem , can you specify .... vendor H/W details will be provided at kernel layer itself via device tree. what is the use case of passing device specific information from application.

Comment: I am new to Linux Device Driver. I got this doubt while trying to understand the char driver. I checked PCI driver  http://www.zarb.org/~trem/kernel/pci/pci-driver.c In the driver code, HW/vendor specific details are part of struct pci_driver, which is then passed to pci_register_driver() during initialization. pci_register_driver() will internally call driver_register() and HW specific details are then maintained in one list inside kernel. When a device is inserted, the driver list will be iterated and a match will be found (binding the driver to device). How this is done for Char Driver ??

Comment: character driver is a standard interface it won't requre any H/W information, inside kernel you can create a new device and device specific H/W will be taken from device tree(ARM SOCS).You can just look around rtc driver , it has a driver/rtc/rtc-dev.c , which is a generic  char driver, there will be one more glue driver specific to your board/HW rtc-****.c which will be having H/W related  information and will fetch from device tree.

Comment: Thanks !! I will check rtc driver.

Answer (score 0):

In a character driver like I2C client driver, We specify the slave address in the client structure's "addr" field and then call i2c_master_send() or i2c_master_receive() on this client . This calls will ultimately go to the main adapter controlling that line and the adapter then communicates with the device specified by the slave address.

And the binding of drivers operations is done mainly with cdev_init() and cdev_add() functions.

Also driver may choose to provide probe() function and let kernel find  and bind all the devices which this driver is capable of supporting.

Comment: I got the above sample code for pci driver. In "struct pci_driver" we are specifying the vendor specific details and probe function. During initialization, we will call pci_register_driver() and pass the address of "pci_driver" struct. Internally, pci_register_driver() will call driver_register(). A device driver list is maintained by bus driver. Now, when a device is inserted, device_register() function will be called and list of devices is also maintained by the Bus driver. Bus driver, will then iterate the list of device driver and device and will find a match based on id_table.

Comment: Is it handled in similar manner for char driver ?? If yes, then please provide some reference. My main doubt is how char driver will pass the vendor/HW specific details to the kernel, which will help the kernel to bind it to corresponding device.